# PHP: Calculating File HASH for Files Larger than 2GB

Tags: php, linux, file-upload, hash

Would you advise please, how to calculate file HASH on files larger than 2GB in PHP?

The only [PHP function known to me is:](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-file.php)

```
string hash_file ( string $algo , string $filename [, bool $raw_output = false ] )
```

This function however has a limitation. It returns HASH for files smaller than 2GB. For larger files, `hash_file()` throws error.

Here are some constraints/requests:

- should work on Linux Ubuntu 64bit server
- compatible with PHP 5+
- there should be no file size limit
- should be as fast as possible

This is all the information I have now. Thank you very much.

---

### UPDATE

I have a solution that is more practical and efficient than any hash calculation from data >2GB.

I have realized, that I do not have to generate hash from complete files that are over 2GB. To uniquely identify any file, calculating hash from say first 10KB of data of any file should be sufficient. Moreover, it will be faster than >2GB calculation. In other words, ability to calculate hash from a data string that is over 2GB probably is not necessary at all.

I will wait for your reactions. In couple of days, I will close this question.

Comment: Are you on a 64bit or 32bit Ubuntu system? You can tell by running `uname -i`

Comment: @Ray, I am on 64bit Ubuntu System. I have installed it by myself so I definitely know.

Comment: Did you try my solution with executing a native process via `exec()` in php?

Comment: @Ray, hi Ray. Not yet. I am busy with something else. As soon as my hands get available, I will test your solution. It should be tomorrow latest. Thank you very much for this idea. I hope, I could gather more possible solutions, so I am ready, when I get back to my problem.

Comment: What solution did you end up using? Calculating the hash of the first 10KB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `exec()` to run a local hashing function in the shell and return the value back to the php script.  Here's an example with `md5` but any algo available can be used.

```
  $results = array();
  $filename = '/full/path/to/file';
  exec("md5sum $filename", $results);
```

Then parse the result array (the output of the shell command).

In general, I like to avoid doing anything directly in PHP that requires more than 1G of memory, especially if running in php-fpm or as an apache module--sort of time reinforced prejudice.   This is definitely my advice when there is a native application that can accomplish the goal and you don't particularly need portablitly cross platform (like run on both linux and windows machines).

Comment: I doubt this will work, because the entire reason 2gb is a limitation is because of using 32-bit installations as opposed to 64 bit, and I don't know any sane host using 32 bit on 64bit architecture.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I think on the command line, even with 32bit systems, the CLI hash functions mdb, sha1, etc... can calculate hashes for files larger than 2gb (not 100% certain though).

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not how it works. The size isn't an arbitrary limitation, it's due to the fact that the maximum amount of characters generated on 32bit architecture is reached at this value. VM a 32bit *nix distro, wget > 2gb file, hash it. You will receive an error.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Interesting, I'll try that when I get a chance.  Would this occur on a 64bit system that php memory limit set to 2gb?  Meaning is the entire file being read into memory?

Comment: Yes, it definitely would. However that would be an arbitrary limitation that has been set by the php.ini, as opposed to a limitation of the systems architecture.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy from a personal preference standpoint, I'm all about discouraging running PHP scripts in the 1G memory and greater range... if this is his constraint (and not a 32bit system) I'd also recommend he us an external shell program to vs. doing it php, but that's oppinion, not technical limitation

Comment: I whole-heartedly agree. :)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Large File Support is about 15 years old now. `md5sum` in a 32bit debian vm works just fine for files over 2GB, as you'd expect. If PHP doesn't, that's purely a PHP bug, not a platform limitation (and definitely not a memory limitation).

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: please delete your wrong comments while it hasn't started spreading.

Comment: @Ray, hi.. +1. Your solution would most likely work for files larger than 2GB. As I have found a solution by myself, where I calculate hash from first 10KB of file data, if nobody else provides answer that will be better than yours, I will mark your answer as the acceptable one.

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori That can work, as long as you're not using the hash for any security verification of file integrity and just for something like bucket storage of files/fast lookup.  Also, if you've calculating hashes for exact naming and not bucketing (i.e. you can't handle duplicates), you need to ensure the files don't have huge repetitive starting blocks (for example, not daily mysql dump files that might have entire tables at the start that didn't change), but you know your data better the anyone on SO.

Comment: @Ray, good points. I have already considered them, and believe I should be fine. I will do couple of tests, and possibly increase the hash chunk size from 10KB to 100KB or possibly 1MB.

Comment: @zerkms I have no intention of deleting my comments.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: but they are wrong. You can save files more than 2gb on 32bit systems. 32bit have **NOTHING TO DO** with FS limitations. People will read it and will think that you're sharing some knowledge, while it's just a bs. Here is something for you to learn: http://www.novell.com/documentation/suse91/suselinux-adminguide/html/apas04.html I hope you can distinguish between 2Gb and 2Tb cannot you?

Comment: @zerkms where did i say anything about saving the file, i stated that if you wish to hash the file then you will encounter issues. learn to read.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: "i stated that if you wish to hash the file then you will encounter issues" --- and that's **wrong**. Learn to learn? Learn to check the facts before you present them as truth? Learn to check the facts before you continue arguing? http://pastebin.com/kuDG1aEN have a good day