# How to get hash value for big file that is over 2GB using php

Tags: php

Is there any solution for computing hash value for files that are bigger than 2GB using php? Either setting the php memory limit to infinity or no limit on execution time is not considered. Thank you.

Comment: Use `system` to invoke a separate executable to compute the hash. E.g. for SHA1 use `system( 'sha1sum "$filePath"');`.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-file.php

Comment: @barmar PHP’s file has high functions have a size limit of 2GB: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640361/php-calculating-file-hash-for-files-larger-than-2gb

Comment: see my comment in manual for hash_file [*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-file.php#122549), stream it in